# Wired vs SMD resistor on 230V optocoupler input

Tags: resistors, mains, opto-isolator

For circuits similar to the one below, we used large wire resistors with proper power rating in our past designs.

[image]

The question came up, if it would be a good idea to replace the resistor with SMD chip resistors (lower cost, less space, easier assembly).

Most 2512 SMD resistors for example are rated for 200V (mainly thick film material). So using two of those in series should work with respect to the voltage.

You can get wired resistors with guaranteed failure mode "open" and non-flammable. Is there some equivalent SMD resistor type available? What material/technology would I look for?

Creepage distance shouldn't be a problem, since the opto coupler properly isolates the rest of the electronic.

Are there any other considerations I missed?

Comment: Does "chip resistor" mean anything special or are we talking about just an smd resistor?

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Yes, SMD resistor in general. I was referring to the very common "chip resistor" package type which would be preferable.

Comment: I'm confused by "chip resistor" and "THT".

Comment: @OlinLathrop By chip resistor he means surface mount, and THT is just through hole technology aka through hole components.

Comment: I've seen carbon surface mount resistors fail short, but usually they fail open (the resistance can dip low before failing open though, so they aren't much protection to the circuit). I've heard metal films can short as well, but never seen it happen. There are fusible resistors that are guaranteed to fail open and they come in both surface mount and through hole. Non flammable coatings exist on surface mount as well. So just include fusible and non-flammable in your search and you're golden. The main benefit to through hole is mounting strength.

Comment: @Olin: SMD resistors on Digikey are under the category "Chip Resistor - Surface Mount", and I've certainly seen the abbreviation THT before. What did he invent?

Comment: @OlinLathrop: My wording could have been better, but as far as I am aware of, "THT" and "chip resistor" are pretty common expressions. However, I changed it to be more consistent. I do not understand the close vote though, as I find it a perfectly valid question.

Comment: What does your safety design requirement (eg. EN60065) say about transient voltages?

Comment: @OlinLathrop Not everyone uses the same terms that you do, and it's not because they're using non-standard terminology. Stop pretending to be confused by these things, it's getting old.

Comment: With regard to fusible through-hole resistors you may often find that the manufacturers produced devices called "fusible" or "flameproof" which look identical apart from a colour band indicating which type it is.  They both fail safely under extreme conditions, it is just that those conditions are more rigorously defined for the "fusible" types - possibly with a financial trade-off for the production planner buying thousands of the things!

Answer (score 3):

SMD resistors are perfectly acceptable for this purpose.  You need to choose your resistors for both voltage and power rating.  You also have the option to use more than two resistors like you have shown: the space occupied by having two resistors in series in each leg (4 resistors total) is still tiny compared to the through-hole resistors you used previously.

Be sure to size your resistors to handle possible over-voltage conditions.  You can also specify resistors that are either fusible or flame-proof if required by your certifying authority.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Do you have a suggestions for a  fitting a product series? Vishay has some "High Power Thin Film" resistors which are flame resistant, but up to 30k Ohm only. Maybe I am not coming up with a proper key word.